# How I can shorten this horrible if-statment?

Tags: python

Does anyone know how I can shorten this without changing the function of it at all?

It is used to check so there are no duplicates between `i[0]`, `i[1]`, `i[3]` and `i[4]` (They are all `list`s). And if you know how to make it a general expression that works with more lists and lists longer than 4 items I would love to know how.

I have tried making it with for-loops but I can't manage to get it working. Mostly because I can manage to compare something in `i[0]` with something in `i[2]` when doing it.

I know the code block is a bit overkill.

```
if (
        # i[0]
        # i[0][0]
        i[1][0] != i[0][0] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[0][0] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[0][0] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[0][0] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[0][0] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[0][0] != i[3][3]
        # i[0][1]
        and i[1][0] != i[0][1] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[0][1] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[0][1] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[0][1] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[0][1] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[0][1] != i[3][3]
        # i[0][2]
        and i[1][0] != i[0][2] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[0][2] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[0][2] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[0][2] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[0][2] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[0][2] != i[3][3]
        # i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[0][3] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[0][3] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[0][3] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[0][3] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[0][3] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[0][3] != i[3][3]
        # i[1]
        # i[1][0]
        and i[0][0] != i[1][0] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[1][0] != i[0][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[1][0] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[1][0] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[1][0] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[1][0] != i[3][3]
        # i[1][1]
        and i[0][0] != i[1][1] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[1][1] != i[0][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[1][1] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[1][1] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[1][1] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[1][1] != i[3][3]
        # i[1][2]
        and i[0][0] != i[1][2] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[1][2] != i[0][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[1][2] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[1][2] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[1][2] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[1][2] != i[3][3]
        # i[1][3]
        and i[0][0] != i[1][3] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[1][3] != i[0][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[1][3] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[1][3] != i[2][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[1][3] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[1][3] != i[3][3]
        # i[2]
        # i[2][0]
        and i[0][0] != i[2][0] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[2][0] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[2][0] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[2][0] != i[1][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[2][0] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[2][0] != i[3][3]
        # i[2][1]
        and i[0][0] != i[2][1] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[2][1] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[2][1] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[2][1] != i[1][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[2][1] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[2][1] != i[3][3]
        # i[2][2]
        and i[0][0] != i[2][2] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[2][2] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[2][2] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[2][2] != i[1][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[2][2] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[2][2] != i[3][3]
        # i[2][3]
        and i[0][0] != i[2][3] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[2][3] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[2][3] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[2][3] != i[1][3]
        and i[3][0] != i[2][3] != i[3][1]
        and i[3][2] != i[2][3] != i[3][3]
        # i[3]
        # i[3][0]
        and i[0][0] != i[3][0] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[3][0] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[3][0] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[3][0] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[3][0] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[3][0] != i[2][3]
        # i[3][1]
        and i[0][0] != i[3][1] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[3][1] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[3][1] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[3][1] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[3][1] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[3][1] != i[2][3]
        # i[3][2]
        and i[0][0] != i[3][2] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[3][2] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[3][2] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[3][2] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[3][2] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[3][2] != i[2][3]
        # i[3][3]
        and i[0][0] != i[3][3] != i[0][1]
        and i[0][2] != i[3][3] != i[0][3]
        and i[1][0] != i[3][3] != i[1][1]
        and i[1][2] != i[3][3] != i[1][3]
        and i[2][0] != i[3][3] != i[2][1]
        and i[2][2] != i[3][3] != i[2][3]
    ):
        best_combinations.append(i)
```

Comment: When you reach situations like this, it's a sign that you should reconsider your design.

Comment: OMG … I think you wrote the longest If-statement that every existed … Would be worth a try to send this to the Guiness Book of World Records team ? ;)

Comment: Do I understand correct that you have a list of lists, and you want to make sure that no element repeats more than once it all of them?

Comment: That is definitely overkill... TLDR: how does the list look like? ``i = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11]]``?

Comment: `from itertools import chain` `if len(set(chain.from_iterable(i))) <= 1`…?

Comment: @deceze it seems that they need all elements to be unique, not all the same.

Comment: @bereal Ah, right… might provide a nudge in the right direction though…

Answer (score 1):

This should work on a list of items of arbitrary length:

```
from itertools import combinations

def is_valid(matrix):
    """Return `True` if all lists in the matrix are entirely unique in their elements.

    Uniqueness is tested relative to the other lists in the matrix.

    Order is irrelevant when testing uniqueness:
    if any one list contains an element that appears anywhere in any other list, 
    the function returns `False`.
    """

    return not any(set(x).intersection(y) for x, y in combinations(matrix, 2))
```

Then you'd just write:

```
if is_valid(i):
    best_combinations.append(i)
```

**How it works**

1. [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) returns an iterator that yields each possible *r*-length combination from a given iterable. We feed it our list of lists, and specify that `r=2`, meaning that `combinations(matrix, 2)` iterates through every possible pair of lists.
2. For every possible pair of lists, we convert the first into a `set`, and use the [`set.intersection`](https://realpython.com/python-sets/) method to find if there are any elements in the second list that were also in the first list.
3. If the `set.intersection` method returns a non-empty set for any possible pair of lists, the function returns `False`. Otherwise, the function returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same checks but programmatically, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```py
from itertools import product

def is_valid(matrix):
    for i, j in product(range(4), range(4)):
        for x, y in product(range(4), range(4)):
            if x == i:
                continue
            if matrix[i][j] == matrix[x][y]:
                return False
    return True
```